# exec: "pwsh": executable file not found in %PATH%

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, powershell-core

I've been trying to initiate my pipeline on gitlab CI/CD for a demo project. I've installed gitlab-runner in my windows local machine and gave the executor type as "Shell". And I've successfully integrated the gitlab-runner with my gitlab project. But whenever I pushed any changes to repo, the pipeline started and end up in "pshw" not found in %PATH error.
[This is error which I'm getting every time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edExb.png)

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: failed to start process: exec: "pwsh": executable file not found in %PATH%. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue and explain what and  why I'm getting this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 68):

When choosing the shell option, the gitlab runner installer uses `pwsh` as the executor. It generates a `config.toml` that looks like

```toml
[[runners]]
  name = "some name"
  url = "http://someurl.com/"
  token = "some-token"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "pwsh"
```

The problem is that pwsh isn't a valid windows command (on my installs). Changing `pwsh` to `powershell` and restarting `gitlab-runner` service fixed the problem for me.

Comment: How do you change the default shell to powershell in the install itself, while doing another install I'm still getting the default shell as pwsh instead of powershell

Comment: @Clueless, Apparently, one cannot specify this during installation/registration rather changing the `config.toml` file

Comment: This is not a solution in case you need features from Powershell Core (`pwsh`)

Comment: The answer isn't much use if you need to use PowerShell Core

Answer (score 23):

Go to the installation directory of GitLab Runner e.g. `C:\Automation\GitLab-Runner`. Here you will see `config.toml` file, open with notepad and replace `"pwsh"` with `"powershell"` as below:

From:

```toml
[[runners]]
  name = "PT-Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "pwsh"             # <----- change to powershell
```

To:

```toml
[[runners]]
  name = "PT-Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"       # <-----
```

Answer (score 6):

The current answers from "Raghwendra Sonu" and "Not a code monkey" work if you do not need features from Powershell Core (v7) and you are fine with using Windows Powershell (v5). If you do need features from Powershell Core then editing your `config.toml` is not a solution.

I had the same problem — I installed Powershell Core from the Microsoft Store and added it to the PATH Environment variable (happened automatically), but I still got the mentioned error within gitlab.

The solution is to not use the Powershell Core from the Microsoft Store, but instead install it like this (at least that worked for me):

```
winget install --id Microsoft.Powershell --source winget
```

And then add it to the PATH via adding `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7` to the PATH.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for. I just could not for the life of me find the path to PowerShell...

Comment: It also took me a while to find that out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify shell during registration with `--shell` parameter, e.g. `bash, sh, cmd, pwsh or powershell`.

```
PS> .\gitlab-runner.exe register `
  --non-interactive `
  --url "https://gitlab.com/" `
  --token "TOKEN" `
  --executor "shell" `
  --shell "powershell" `
  ...
```