# How can I fix the problem about slow CICD by gitlab runner?

Tags: performance, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, powershell-core

When I used the GitLab runner to run CICD in my project, I found the pipeline ran quite slowly, and it even did not pass the first stage of the work. I set my runner executor as "pwsh". I also downloaded PowerShell 7 for Windows. The following is my .yml file:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

Build Job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "This is a first sample Build Job."

Test Job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This is a first sample Test Job."

Deploy Job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This is a first sample Deploy Job."
```

I cannot figure out why the runner can not finish this basic pipeline in just a few seconds. It had ran for 11 minutes in the build stage.

Here is my runner information:

```ini
[[runners]]
  name = "Local_TYC"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = 23245609
  token = "glrt-xxxxxx"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "pwsh"
```

I looked at a website to first solve the problem of pwsh path not found:
[exec: "pwsh": executable file not found in %PATH%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68109273/exec-pwsh-executable-file-not-found-in-path)

It seemed to work and successfully connect to my runner. And I also put the path of Powershell 7 from windows to the environment variable.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.